# nextjs13 local fetch returns 500 - how to make work with context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Currently trying to switch to nextjs 13 and running into issues on the fetch return. I'm using the new AppRouter and the folder structure looks like this:

```
/app
  /context
    index.tsx
  /measurement
    route.ts
```

I have a Context Provider `/app/context/index.tsx`:

```
export const MeasurementContext = createContext([]);

const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args);

const MeasurementProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [elements, setElements] = useState([]);
  const [useSwr, setUseSwr] = useState(false);
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useSWR(useSwr ? "/measurement" : null, fetcher);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!elements.length) {
      setUseSwr(true);
    }
  }, [elements]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setUseSwr(false);
    data && setElements(data);
  }, [data]);

  return <MeasurementContext.Provider value={elements}>{children}</MeasurementContext.Provider>;
};

export default MeasurementProvider;
```

and the route handler `/app/measurement/route.ts`:

```
export async function GET() {
  try {
    const data = await getMeasurements();

    if (data.length) {
      return data;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e, "error msg");
  }
}
```

I'm seeing a valid return with data from the route but in the context provider I'm getting a 500 status with Internal Server Error.

This is what I've tried:

- used NextResponse to return data as json
- tried using generic fetch AND moved fetch function to several components to test a difference in response

How do I combine locally fetched data from a route with React context in NextJS 13?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you might be missing the step of returning the data as a NextResponse object in your route handler.

In your /app/measurement/route.ts file, you should return the data using NextResponse.json(). Here's how you can do it:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function GET() {
  try {
    const data = await getMeasurements();

    if (data.length) {
      return NextResponse.json(data);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e, "error msg");
  }
}
```

This will ensure that the data is returned as a JSON response, which can then be consumed by your context provider.

Also, make sure that your fetcher function in the context provider is correctly handling the response and converting it to JSON. Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
const fetcher = async (...args) => {
  const res = await fetch(...args);
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('An error occurred while fetching the data.');
  }
  return res.json();
};
```

This fetcher function will throw an error if the response status is not ok (200-299), and otherwise it will return the response data as JSON. This can help you catch and handle errors in your SWR hook.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow, CyberJ.

It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the current policies since at least *eight* of of your answers yesterday appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.